# Snap, two options to install the same app?

Tags: software-installation, software-center, snap

Question solved. If you do not want to use 'Snap', install everything via the terminal `sudo apt-get install ...`.

I don't care what snap is for. I don't want a different option to install a program. It is also not clear which snap is and which is not. I don't want `/home/user/snap`. I hope someone can help me.

It's rather irritating in Ubuntu software, which one to install? It is unclear. For example screenshots: Firefox, Gimp, LibreOffice and Inkscape. There is a difference, to install it "normally" or in `/home/user/snap`. Also the design is different. I've been having this trouble for years. Can anyone help me to solve this?

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: ***If you do not want to use 'Snap', install everything via the terminal `sudo apt-get install ...`***: But if you prefer GUI over command-line, you can simply scroll to the bottom of the app details page. There you can find if that is a snap package or deb package from repositories (and yes repository details too).